# any ethereum web wallet without running local node

Tags: external-api

any php script for eth web wallet without ruining a  local node on my server? So I can integrate the web wallet into my site without running local node on my server.
By the way, how big the size of the eth local node will be and how much bandwidth required?
possible to put the local node on one server and the web wallet on another server? need some setting for rpc call?
Thanks